# Preserve form data when switching pages

Tags: javascript, html

```html
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="foo">
    </form>

    <a href="b.html">
        b.html
    </a>
```

This piece of code is on `a.html`. If someone enters some value `hello world` into the text box and clicks on the link to go to `b.html`, and then he goes back to `a.html` by hitting back button. Will the form state (text box `hello world`) be preserved?

I have tested it in Chrome and it is fine the value will be populated back.

I just wanted to know how this behaviour is going to happen in other major browsers? support mobile browser?

Comment: what do you want? if you want to autocomplete user input, just add autocomplete to input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is built into all major browsers (Chrome, Safari, Firefox, latest versions of IE) and at least Chrome for Android. I'm pretty sure it works for iOS as well (not sure for all mobile browsers, there are a lot of different phones/versions these days).